# hibernate doesn't create all the associated tables

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

i have three entity classes. and by using spring boot i am trying to create all those three tables. but it only creates one table out of three.

my all three classes are:-

**Users.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@Column(name="email", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String email;
private String phone;
private boolean enabled=true;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "users", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

---------------------getter setters--------------------------------
}
```

**UserRole.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_role")
public class UserRole {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long userRoleId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private Users users;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="role_id")
private Role role;

===============getter setters==============================
}
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_role")
public class UserRole {

@Id
private long roleId;
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

==============getter setters ====================
```

i expect hibernate to create three tables but on my case only one table roles is being created and i get error like

Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [create table user_role (user_role_id numeric(19,0) identity not null, role_id numeric(19,0), user_id numeric(19,0), primary key (user_role_id))]

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identity not null, role_id numeric(19,0), user_id numeric(19,0), primary key (us' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

The error states you are trying to use 'IDENTITY NOT NULL' in MySQL database engine, which is not valid. IDENTITY is a SQL SERVER keyword.

Make sure you have Hibernate correctly configured for your database engine. You should be using MySQLDialect.

In your application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: i changed all the @GeneratedValue to Auto still the same error

Comment: thanks a lot. i actually was missing MySQL5InnoDBDialect in application.properties.

Comment: @sagarlimbu Great! If you found the answer useful to the problem, it would be nice if you could mark it as approved.